# How to use multiple neo4j databases in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j

I am trying to configure my Spring Boot application to use multiple neo4j databases. I could not find any example of it on the web and thought I should ask.

Should we define the settings in the *.properties* for each database?
Should we define a Driver bean for each in the config class?
How should we know which Neo4jTemplate is used?

**Edit:**
I have 2 different settings in my .properties

```
###Neo4j db1
spring.neo4j.db1.uri=bolt://localhost:17486
spring.neo4j.db1.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.db1.authentication.password=pass
spring.data.neo4j.db1.database=db1

##Neo4j db2
spring.neo4j.db2.uri=bolt://localhost:17486
spring.neo4j.db2.authentication.username=neo4j
spring.neo4j.db2.authentication.password=pass
spring.data.neo4j.db2.database=db2
```

I have the corresponding Configuration classes. I am not going to have them both here but the missing one almost identical except for the meaningful Qualifier names.

```
@Configuration
@EnableNeo4jRepositories(basePackages = "com.horsefly.companymodel.repository.db1")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class Neo4jDB1 {

    @Value("${spring.neo4j.db1.uri}")
    private String uri;

    @Value("${spring.neo4j.db1.authentication.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${spring.neo4j.db1.authentication.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.data.neo4j.db1.database}")
    private String databaseName;

    @Bean(name = "db1Driver") //same for db2
    public Driver db1Driver() {
        return GraphDatabase.driver(uri, AuthTokens.basic(username, password));
    }

    @Bean(name = "db1TransactionManager") //same for db2
    public Neo4jTransactionManager neo4jTransactionManager() {
        return new Neo4jTransactionManager(db1Driver());
    }

    @Bean(name = "neo4jClientdb1")// same for db2
    public Neo4jClient neo4jClientdb1() {
        DatabaseSelectionProvider databaseSelectionProvider = () -> DatabaseSelection.byName("db1"); //entered manually.
        return Neo4jClient.create(db1Driver(), databaseSelectionProvider);
    }

    @Bean(name="neo4jTemplatedb1") // same for db2
    public Neo4jTemplate neo4jTemplate(@Qualifier("neo4jClientdb1") Neo4jClient client, Neo4jMappingContext neo4jMappingContext) {
        return new Neo4jTemplate(client, neo4jMappingContext);
    }
}
```

When I ran the app, I saw the below, although I have qualifiers to distinguish them

```
required a bean named 'neo4jTemplate' that could not be found.
Action:Consider defining a bean named 'neo4jTemplate' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Check this out :- https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/reference/faq.html#faq.multidatabase

Comment: @HarryCoder The link is for Spring Data JPA, I am interested in Neo4J

Comment: @AmolGharpure Thanks but the info is insufficient and unclear.

Comment: Just to give the right answer: Do you only want to switch the database within one Neo4j instance? Or, do you want to really create separate driver instances because you try to connect to different Neo4j instances? From the example it looks like it is _just_ the database.

Comment: @meistermeir I would like to be able to connect two different databases at the same time. It should be like having 2 different data source configuration classes for MySQL databases.

Comment: @Cugomastik If I understood it right, the idea would be then the same as in this test case https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/bb97a751d7384b8b00764ac71d0023f469508fc4/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/integration/multiple_ctx_imperative/MultipleContextsIT.java#L53 please have a look at the configs `Domain1/2Config` also)